# Why such a huge difference in time creating a table via script vs INSERT SELECT?

Tags: mysql, performance, perl, create-table

I created a small Perl script to insert a large number of entries to a table.
Sample snippet:

```
$query = "insert into big_table (first_name, last_name) values (?, ?) ";

# prepare your statement for connecting to the database
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);

for(my $i = 1; $ i <= 70000; i++) {  
    my $first = "test".$i;  
    my $last = "test".$i;   
    $statement->execute($first, $last);   
}
```

It inserted the rows and it took around 15 mins

But when I did this:

```
CREATE TABLE big_table2 like big_table;  
INSERT INTO big_table2 SELECT * FROM big_table;
```

It took only 55 seconds! For 70000 rows
Why such a huge difference?

Comment: Most likely culprit is transaction overhead (each transaction can force a disk write). Try wrapping the for loop as a single transaction, see if performance improves.

Answer (score 6):

To speed up the insertion through the loop you can try with a transaction :

Add  `AutoCommit=>0` attribute to the connection :

```
my $connection = DBI->connect($dsn,$username,$password, AutoCommit=>0); # transaction enabled
```

Then after the for loop you can commit your all changes in a single atomic operation :

```
$connection->commit();
```

The difference in performance that you noticed is imputable at the several operations that you do in the for loop, you are executing a query and writing to disk 70000 times, while with the other query only one time with all the records ...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps because the script has to write to disk 70,000 times, whereas the INSERT SELECT minimizes the disk I/O.

Furthermore, you can simplify your SQL as such: [[create table select syntax]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html)

```
create table big_table2 select * from big_table;
```

I think there's no need to write a Perl script for what you can do in a SQL script.

Comment: `I think there's no need to write a Perl script for what you can do in a SQL script.` I did not know how to create the original 70000 rows from SQL

Comment: @aleroot But still, there's no need to write a Perl script.

Answer (score 2):

**Why such a big difference?**

Because each one of those individual INSERT statements (from the script) has to be sent to the database, where it has to be parsed (checked for syntax and semantics... keywords and identifiers are in appropriate positions, identifiers are valid, user has privileges on objects,... then MySQL has to develop an execution plan (executable code to actually perform the operation, for the insert it's pretty simple, but it still has to be done), then MySQL has to perform the operation (locate the data and index blocks to be modified, obtain the necessary locks, make the required block changes, check for index violations, fire triggers, etc. then write the block changes to the binary/replication log (either binary logging or statement logging), and then commit the changes, release the locks, cleanup resources, and return a status to the caller. If this is running from a remote machine, those roundtrips to and from the database over the network add to the time.

So, there is overhead for each statement. It's not huge for an individual statement, but for a lot of statements, it starts to add up fast (or add up slowly).

MySQL has a LOT less work to do with the single INSERT statement.

Which is why we try, whenever possible, to avoid processing individual rows in a loop RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row.)

---

MySQL has an optimization that can speed up INSERT, inserting multiple rows in the same statement...

```
INSERT INTO mytable (mycol1, mycol2) VALUES ('a','a'),('b','b'),('c','c')
```

But, before you go hog wild on the number of rows, there's a limit on the maximum size of a SQL statement; I believe the number of bytes is limited by `max_allowed_packet`. (Be aware that limit is bytes, not characters, just in case you are using UTF-8 and some of characters require two or more bytes.)

---

To generate the 70,000 rows in MySQL, without the need for a script, you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (first_name, last_name)
SELECT CONCAT('test',i.i) AS first_name
     , CONCAT('test',i.i) AS last_name
  FROM ( SELECT 1 + ten_thousands.digit*10000
                  + thousands.digit*1000
                  + hundreds.digit*100 
                  + tens.digit*10 
                  + ones.digit
                AS i
           FROM ( SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
                                    UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
                ) ten_thousands
          CROSS
           JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
                                    UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 
                                    UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
                ) thousands
          CROSS
           JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
                                    UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 
                                    UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
                ) hundreds
          CROSS
           JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
                                    UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 
                                    UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
                ) tens 
          CROSS
           JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
                                    UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 
                                    UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
                ) ones
          ORDER
             BY ten_thousands.digit
              , thousands.digit
              , hundreds.digit
              , tens.digit
              , ones.digit
       ) i
```

Comment: I think you went overboard on this answer.

Comment: +1 but I am not sure about the explanation in the first part.I use a prepared statement which is precompiled and reused and I loop over the same db connection binding values to the same precompiled SQL statement. So why would the overhead you mention (parsing/privileges/execution plan etc..) occur?

Comment: @Jim: If server side prepared statements are enabled, then you are right, some of the statement processing I said was being performed is eliminated on subsequent executions.  With the DBD::mysql library that I'm using, **server side** prepared statements are **not** enabled *unless* I include **`mysql_server_prepare=1`** in the connect. Absent that, its the *client* side that performs the replacement of the placeholders, and the client sends SQL text containing literals to the server.